# If I set contentBase path of dev-server, webpack doesn't serve updated files

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am trying to set-up environment for my project, but I am having an issue with `webpack-dev-server`.

If I use following config and do not add `devServer` config object everything works fine. I can open my project go into `dist` and then I will see my project which will update if I change something in my `.ts` files, but when I add option and set `contentBase` then after i run `webpack-dev-server` it will open `dist` but with old `bundle.js` file which will never update.

Is there any way how I can set default `url` of dev server and see changes after I change something in my files ?

What I tried:

- add `watchOptions: { poll: true }`
- add `watchContentBase: true`
- add `hot: true`
- add custom port `port: 9000`

> It didn't helped at all.

Below you can find my `webpack.config.json`:

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  devtool: 'eval-source-map',
  entry: './src/index.ts',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        include: [
            path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [
        '.ts',
        '.js'
    ]
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    watchContentBase: true,
    hot: true,
    port: 9000,
    watchOptions: {
      poll: true
    }
  },
  output: {
    publicPath: 'dist',
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  }
};
```

> If I remove `devServer` config object than everything works fine but I have to choose url to `dist` manually

Comment: Have you tried to set a port property to e.g. 9000 inside of the devServer object? Also the documentation says "If you're having trouble, navigating to the /webpack-dev-server route will show where files are served. For example, http://localhost:9000/webpack-dev-server." Maybe after setting a port, you can navigate to that and get more info?

Comment: @OliverF. I also tried this and it didn't help :/

Comment: Where is your index.html located? In public or also in dist?

Comment: Also in `dist` directory. If you want I can add screenshot of my project directory structure

Comment: Could you maybe try to remove the publicPath from the output and move it to the devServer? So that not the output is served there but the devServer output.

Comment: It didn't help :/

Comment: Are you also injecting the new generated output file in the html? Maybe check https://linguinecode.com/post/how-to-setup-webpack-dev-server-react-babel, it is fitting pretty well with your usecase and config. Ignore the react stuff but https://linguinecode.com/post/how-to-setup-webpack-dev-server-react-babel#setup-htmlwebpack-plugin is an example of how to autoinject those new generated files in the html. When the html serves the static js instead of the hot, then you will of course never see any changes.

Comment: I think injecting `.js` files is not a problem because if I do not set this `dist` as default url then everything works fine. I can also see that file is loaded correctly in network section of chrome devtools (but it is old and not updated)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in `publicPath` definition. **`publicPath`** was declared incorrectly. **`publicPath`** should be initialized with `/` but in my config it was `dist`. So that was the reason why webpack didn't update `bundle.js`, because it was watching wrong directory.

So the correct config should look like that:

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  devtool: 'eval-source-map',
  entry: './src/index.ts',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        include: [
            path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [
        '.ts',
        '.js'
    ]
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'dist')
  },
  output: {
    publicPath: '/', // NOW PUBLIC PATH IS CORRECT
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Okay so I recreated your solution and this worked for me:

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  devtool: 'eval-source-map',
  entry: './src/index.ts',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        include: [
          path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [
      '.ts',
      '.js'
    ]
  },
  devServer: {
    publicPath: '/',
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'public/dist'),
    watchContentBase: true,
    hot: true,
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 3000,
    watchOptions: {
      poll: true
    }
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'public/dist')
  },
  plugins: [
    // Re-generate index.html with injected script tag.
    // The injected script tag contains a src value of the
    // filename output defined above.
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      inject: true,
      template: path.join(__dirname, 'public/index.html'),
    }),
  ],
};
```

Then I ran `npx webpack-dev-server`.
The html looked like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="root"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the structure of the project is:

[image]

After that, the hot reload worked like a charm at http://localhost:3000/.
Hope that helped!

Comment: But the problem was different. Actually I defined `publicPath` incorrectly. it should be `/` but in my config it was `dist`. So probably that was the reason why webpack didn't update `bundle.js` (because) it was watching wrong directory

Comment: That is true yes.